# Add a non default signature in Outlook by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

There are many posts about how to add a default signature in drafting a new email in outlook by VBA.

However, is there any way to choose which signature to insert in the email? I am writing a VBA to copy data from excel and then draft a new email in outlook with non-default signature.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not just enter the closing "signature" programmatically instead of using a "saved signature"?

Comment: ... I have not done it myself, but I know the bookmark `Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")` would be involved.  Might be helpful to search for examples with that.

Comment: the signature is composed of several pictures and texts. it will be better to use saved signature

Comment: ...I don't understand: *either way* you're adding it programmatically, and can be re-used whether it's saved as a "signature", or saved as a `Sub`...

Comment: are you aware that **you *can* save signatures *without* VBA**?

Answer (score 1):

In order to include a non-standard signature you would need to open the signature template from the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Signatures` folder, and append the contents of the appropriate file to your message body.

```
.... 'Your other code to create the mailitem "msg" goes here.'

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\mySig2.htm", ForReading)
strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

msg.HTMLBody = msg.HTMLBody & strText
```

Comment: thanks for your help, however it shows that run time error 5: invalid procedure call or argument when i run the line *Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("%AppData%\Microsoft\Signatures\mySig2.htm", ForReading)

Comment: i tested the htm link works but the whole line does not work

Comment: @rlau You may need to add a reference to your project for the Windows Script Host Object Model (wshom.ocx)